# lo-dash : JSON parsing and returning required output

Tags: lodash

I am new to lodash and have below queries. i have attach a sample json of mine. I referred many other post but nothing worked for me

- i want to find array with state as true and return below values

  1. name only
  2. name and partno
- i also want to just return state and name

```js
[{
  'state': true,
  'partno': 21,
  'idno': 1,
  'name': 'abc'
 },
 {
  'state': true,
  'partno': 22,
  'idno': 2,
  'name': 'xyz'
 },
 {
  'state': false,
  'partno': 23,
  'idno': 3,
  'name': 'mnd'
 },
 {
  'state': true,
  'partno': 26,
  'idno': 4,
  'name': 'koi'
 },
 {
  'state': false,
  'partno': 21,
  'idno': 1,
  'name': 'abc'
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code does what you need

```js
const data = getData();

console.log('I want to...\n\n');


console.log('1. find array with state as true and return name only')
const result1 = _(data)
  .filter('state')
  .map('name')
  .value();

// logAsJson is a helper function below
logAsJson(result1);
     
     
console.log('2. find array with state as true and return name and partno');
const result2 = _(data)
  .filter('state')
  // pickProperties is a helper function below
  .map(pickProperties(['name', 'partno']))
  .value();
logAsJson(result2);


console.log('3. just return state and name');
const result3 = _.map(data, pickProperties(['state', 'name']));
logAsJson(result3);


//
// Helper functions
//

function logAsJson(anObject) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(anObject, null, 2));
}

function pickProperties(propsToPick) {
  return function mapperFn(anObject) {
    return _.pick(anObject, propsToPick);
  };
}

function getData() {
  return [
    {
      'state': true,
      'partno': 21,
      'idno': 1,
      'name': 'abc'
    },
    {
      'state': true,
      'partno': 22,
      'idno': 2,
      'name': 'xyz'
    },
    {
      'state': false,
      'partno': 23,
      'idno': 3,
      'name': 'mnd'
    },
    {
      'state': true,
      'partno': 26,
      'idno': 4,
      'name': 'koi'
    },
    {
      'state': false,
      'partno': 21,
      'idno': 1,
      'name': 'abc'
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get your question, but here is what you requested:

```
//Filters your array and creates a new object
yourArray.filter(x => x.state)
       .map( x => ({'name':x.name, 'partno':x.partno}))
```

I didn't know lodash, but taking a look at the documentation, I came with this:

```
_map(_.filter(yourArray, 'state'), (x) => ({'name':x.name,'partno':x.partno})
```

Which is pretty much the same. Is there a reason why are you using lodash for this?

Comment: in lodash you can use chaining: `_(yourArray).map(...).filter(...).value()` (value fn is necessary to return final output)

Comment: @Z.Khullah Still, seems more trouble for something you can easily achieve with the standard library.